# how do you stub/expect a state_machine event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state-machine

I want to do something like this:

```
@vehicle.should_receive(:park)
@vehicle.stub!(:park)
Vehicle.any_instance.stub(:park)
# etc.
```

so that I can validate interaction or use a state_machine in other specs without the overhead of actually changing states...

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Just stub or set an expectation as you would with any other instance method. Or are we missing something?

Comment: It sure does work, thanks! turns out the class I was testing was using a different instance of the state_machine other than the one I set expectations on... I hadn't realized.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the above methods you wrote about. Note, that I think in some versions of Rspec, stubbing directly, or with #should_receive will replace the body of said stubbed method. If you later test for side effects, they won't be present.

Usually I work around this with.

```
@vehicle.should_receive(:park) do
   @vehicle.state = :parked
end

expect do
  @person.exit_vehicle
end.should change(@vehicle.state).from(:driving).to(:parked)
```